# Guice: injecting factory-generated instances properly

Tags: java, groovy, dependency-injection, guice

I'm using Guice 3.0 on a Groovy project and am running into bizarre/unexpected injection behaviors. My main/bootstrapping class:

```
class WidgetServicePerfTester {
    @Inject
    WidgetGenerator widgetGenerator

    static main(args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new WidgetServicePerfTesterModule())
        WidgetServicePerfTester perfTester = injector.getInstance(WidgetServicePerfTester)

        perfTester.run()
    }

    void run() {
        List<Widget> widgets = widgetGenerator.generateWidgets()
        widgets.each {
            it.doStuff()
        }
    }
}
```

My POJO:

```
class Widget extends Thingy {
    WidgetClient widgetClient

    int numFoos

    @Override
    void doStuff() {
        widgetClient.doSomethingOnServer()
    }
}
```

My POJO generators (API + impl):

```
interface WidgetGenerator {
    List<Widget> generateWidgets()
}

class SimpleWidgetGenerator implements WidgetGenerator {
    @Inject
    WidgetClient widgetClient

    int numWidgets

    SimpleWidgetGenerator() {
        super()
    }

    SimpleWidgetGenerator(int numWidgets) {
        super()

        this.numWidgets = numWidgets
    }

    @Override
    List<Widget> generateWidgets() {
        List<Widget> widgets = []

        Widget firstWidget = new Widget(widgetClient: widgetClient, numFoos: getRandomNumber())
        widgets.add(firstWidget)

        // Code that populates the rest of 'widgets' with 'numWidgets' number of Widgets.
    }
}
```

My Guice module:

```
class WidgetServicePerfTesterModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(WidgetClient).to(SimpleWidgetClient)
    }

    @Provides
    public WidgetGenerator provideSimpleWidgetGenerator() {
        new SimpleWidgetGenerator(50)
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get null pointer exceptions because the `WidgetClient` injected into each `Widget` is NULL. **Why and what's the fix?**

Comment: There's no `WidgetClient` and `SimpleWidgetClient` defined. As well as `Thingy`. Could you provide implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole problem begins here in `WidgetServicePerfTesterModule` class, in the following block of code:

```
@Provides
public WidgetGenerator provideSimpleWidgetGenerator() {
    new SimpleWidgetGenerator(50)
}
```

An instance of `SimpleWidgetGenerator` is created using this constructor:

```
SimpleWidgetGenerator(int numWidgets) {
    super()
    this.numWidgets = numWidgets
}
```

and since this object is created manually injecting `WidgetClient` into `SimpleWidgetGenerator` will not work - it's null and it's explainable.

To fix the problem `guice-assistedinject` should be used and factory for Widgets should be created. [Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/27918155) you can find refactored project using the mentioned extensions. Everything works fine.

Is that clear now?

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - so I guess I'm looking for a good guideline to go by when it comes to using `guice-assistedinject`. This solution works but I never would have guessed it in a million years. What's the rule of thumb here? When should one use `FactoryModuleBuilder`? What problems does it solve? Thanks again!

Comment: `FactoryModuleBuilder` should be used when you need to create object that has fields annotated with `@Inject` as well as fields that can't be injected - e.g. name of a student from DB. Then using assisted inject you can both pass a constructor argument and have field injected. It seems that that's what you need here.

Comment: If the problem has been solved please accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry @Opal you've been so helpful here (+2 for last 2 comments), I don't mean to revoke the green check, but there is just 1 last item about your code that I'm still not following.  Where is your `WidgetFactory` impl and how is it injected?

Comment: `WidgetFactory` is implemented by guice itself, you just need to define factory method(s) and install the factory with the following statement `install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(WidgetFactory))`. That's all.

Comment: @smeeb is there anything else I can help You or the problem has been solved?